# Реализация алгоритма Дейкстры в книге "Грокаем Алгоритмы"

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Этот код полностью списан из книги, но выполнить я его не могу из-за ошибки на строке 42 типа: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'.

В чем проблема?

```
graph = {}
graph['start'] = {}
graph['start']['A'] = [6]
graph['start']['B'] = [2]
graph['A'] = {}
graph['A']['fin'] = [1]
graph['B'] = {}
graph['B']['A'] = [3]
graph['B']['fin'] = [5]
graph['fin'] = {}

infinity = float('inf')
costs = {}
costs['A'] = 6
costs['B'] = 2
costs['fin'] = infinity

parenst = {}
parenst['A'] = 'start'
parenst['B'] = 'start'
parenst['fin'] = None

processed = []

def find_lowest_cost_node(costs): # определяет узел с наименьшей стоимостью 
    lowest_cost = float('inf')
    lowest_cost_node = None
    for node in costs:
        cost = costs[node]
        if cost < lowest_cost and node not in processed:
            lowest_cost = cost
            lowest_cost_node = node
    return lowest_cost_node

node = find_lowest_cost_node(costs)
while node is not None:
    cost = costs[node]
    neighbors = graph[node]
    for n in neighbors.keys():
        new_cost = cost + neighbors[n] # строка 42
        if costs[n] > new_cost:
            costs[n] = new_cost
            parenst[n] = node
    processed.append(node)
    node = find_lowest_cost_node(costs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

значения у графов должны быть без скобок

```
graph = {}
graph['start'] = {}
graph['start']['A'] = 6
graph['start']['B'] = 2
graph['A'] = {}
graph['A']['fin'] = 1
graph['B'] = {}
graph['B']['A'] = 3
graph['B']['fin'] = 5
graph['fin'] = {}
```

и чтобы вывести результат допишите

```
print(processed)
```

Comment: Само собой, но там была проблема в другом. Мне помог пользователь ниже.

Comment: ниже костыль.поскольку эти скобки означают списки, а нужны целые числа.

Comment: страница 172 дана правильная запись (без скобок)

Answer (score 0):

Вот так ругаться не будет, но я не очень понимаю, что у вас происходит и почему у вас список из одного элемента в `neighbors[n]`

```
new_cost = cost + neighbors[n][0]
```

Comment: Говорю же, с учебника все. Но в любом случае спасибо, внимательность сильно падает, когда полностью опираешься на учебник.